# Binomial Theorem proof using Cauchy Induction

Tags: calculus, induction, binomial-theorem

By differentiating the nth binomial expansion, it is possible to deduce the (n-1)th expansion is true. Is it possible to then show that the nth expansion implies the k*nth expansion for some positive integer k?

Second question: Can the binomial theorem be proven by integrating the nth expansion?

Answer (score 0):

You can almost get the answer, albeit with some cheating.

First, $(x+y)^n=x^n(1+(y/x))^n$, so we can reduce this to showing:

$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k$$
$$(1+x)^{n+1}=(n+1)\int_{-1}^x(1+t)^{n}dt=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{n+1}{k+1}(x^{k+1}-(-1)^{k+1}).$$

$$\binom{n}{k}\frac{n+1}{k+1}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n+1-(k+1))!}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}.$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{n+1}{k+1}(x^{k+1}-(-1)^{k+1})=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}x^{k}+1=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}x^k,$$

where we reindexed the sum and used the fact that $(1-1)^{n+1}=0$. This last bit cheats in a way because we need to know that $(1-1)^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+1}{k}(-1)^k$.

Comment: Can't that last bit be proven by other means?